# Swift value Initialization `= Type()` safe and has a default value?

Tags: swift, initialization, default-value

Somewhere along my Swift journey, someone convinced me that...

```
var myFloat = Float()
```

...initializes `myFloat` with a default value (in this case, 0.0). So in effect, it's the same as...

```
var myFloat: Float = 0.0
```

After a colleague asked for proof of this (especially that there's no crash potential if the original `myFloat` is accessed before it's been changed elsewhere, I've searched Apple Documentation for a bit, and I'm not finding a definitive answer. Anyone happen to know of any well-documented sources or have proof this assertion is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you look at the [documentation for `Float`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float)? In particular, its [`init()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1539945-init)

Comment: Thanks, yeah see discussion @rmdaddy's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1539945-init) for the `init()` of `Float`, it states:

> Creates a value initialized to zero.

So yes, the lines:

```
var myFloat = Float()
```

and

```
var myFloat: Float = 0.0
```

give the same result. A variable named `myFloat` with a type of `Float` and a value of `0.0`.

Personally I like the 2nd option because it is explicit. And for some types, it is shorter:

```
var myDouble = 0.0
var myInt = 0
var myBool = false
```

Comment: Ah, duh. Yeah, since `Float()` is effectually the same as `Float.init()`, you're right. Good call.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like that `Type.init()` syntax. I much prefer `Type()` when initializing.

Comment: Roger that. I've been using `= Float()` when I initialize a property, but I'll change the value before usage (such as grabbing a value from a storyboard). Guess it's a preference thing.

Comment: Of course you can do `var myFloat = Float(0)` to make it clear as well.